# TcpClient send/close problem

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, send

Do I need to close the connection to have messages actually sent? Because whether I use send command or use a network stream, my messages don't get processed until I close connection. Is that the way it's supposed to be or am I missing something?

Ok here's the code.

```
private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      client = new TcpClient();
      client.Connect(ip, port);
      netStream = client.GetStream();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}

private void disconnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (client != null)
   {
      if (client.Connected)
      {
         client.Close();
         client = null;
      }
   }
}

private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   byte[] cmd = ToByteArray("bla bla bla");
   netStream.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
   netStream.Flush();
}
```

I don't think it has to do with this method but have a look.

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(string str)
{
   System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
   return encoding.GetBytes(str);
}
```

Comment: what classes  are u using? + Paste a code example.

Comment: all your code are belong to us.

Comment: What does ToByteArray look like?

Comment: Just a side note not related to your problem but according to MSDN: "You must close the NetworkStream when you are through sending and receiving data. Closing TcpClient does not release the NetworkStream." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx

Comment: Guys maybe it is a problem about the software that listens this port. I don't wanna take anyone's time for no reason. Thx all.

Comment: @joshua - Yeah, I think it might be the other side, this part looks good to me.

Comment: I, too, think it's the code listening on the other side. If that code is doing something like a `ReadToEnd`, it's going to hang until the sender closes its output stream.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably using buffered streams, try to call the .Flush method, which is also automatically called when clode is invoked.

Comment: Hmm looks like I have a NetworkStream issue here like you said. Flush doesn't work but close/dispose does. Now I need to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

No; they'll get sent out, possibly after a 200ms delay.

There must be something else wrong.

Comment: I used NoDelay option. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: `NoDelay` should hardly ever be used. Hence my conclusion that there must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are blocking the main thread from executing after you [Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.write.aspx), this could prevent the message pump for running and not sending your data.  So if you release the main thread (close your data stream), it might seem like that is fixing it, but really is the releasing of the main thread that is allow the data to be processed and written.

If you do wish to block for the data to be written, make sure you use [BeginWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginwrite.aspx) like this:

```
void clientThread()
{
   writeStream.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, myCallback, networkStream);
   resetEvent.WaitOne(timeout);
}
void myCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   NetworkStream myNetworkStream = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;
   myNetworkStream.EndWrite(ar);
   resetEvent.Set();
}
```

Comment: @joshua - No problem, if you post some code we might be able to help out more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) in action. Try enabling [NoDelay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname.aspx) socket option using [SetSocketOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e160993d.aspx) method. But be careful, disabling Nagle's algorithm will downgrade the throughput.