# C# does not send socket data until Socket is closed

Tags: c#, sockets

I am writing a C# app to communicate with a server via a set of 4-10 byte packets. The server is written in Java, and I can put data to it, however, the only way to actually push the packet to the server is by calling the Close() method on the ServerStream, which is not possible for my purposes, as the server emits a packet back to the sender. I have already tried setting

```
socket.NoDelay = true;
socket.Client.NoDelay = true;
```

which does not work. Nor does the Flush() method, because it's not yet implemented. The interesting part is, when I have to force-close the application, the server complains that the connection was reset.

The code follows

```
socket.NoDelay = true;
socket.Client.NoDelay = true;
socket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 6789);
serverStream = socket.GetStream();
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ping");
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
serverStream.Flush();
byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)socket.ReceiveBufferSize);
string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
Console.WriteLine(returndata);
```

If I were to add the line `serverStream.Close();` after where the Flush() method is, the server receives the packet just fine.

What am I doing wrong with my communications layer? Do I just need to use larger packets or is the Nagle algorithm still active?

Comment: Possible answer here:  [Why doesn't “Flush” force the bytes down the network stream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008115/c-sharp-why-doesnt-flush-force-the-bytes-down-the-network-stream)

Comment: I'm actually almost positive that's the explanation. I'd consider posting your comment as an answer.

Comment: `byte[] inStream = new byte[10025]; serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)socket.ReceiveBufferSize);` You have a problem here. The 3rd parameter to `Read()` should be 10025.

Comment: Is your server perhaps expecting a newline? What happens if your message isn't `"ping"`, but rather `"ping\n"`?

Comment: Indeed, the implementation of "Flush" on the NetworkStream class is just as follows:  {} - i.e. nothing.

Comment: Further research shows that the call to "Write" on the NetworkStream will essentially translate into a direct (and unbuffered) call to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx on the socket that is behind the stream - if the data gets stuck, it's there.